# TextWatcher causing a stackOverflow

Tags: android, listener, stack-overflow

Basically, I have got an `Editable` (in this case it's a `TextView`) which has a `TextChangedListener` (a `TextWatcher`) and my question is how can I **not** cause a `stackOverflow` when editing it inside the `afterTextChanged` callback of the `TextWatcher`?

**Some code**

```
private void writeNewMsg() {
    final EditText newMsgText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.s4_et_message);
    newMsgText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            newMsgText.setText(Smiley.getSmiledText(Messaging.this, newMsgText.getText().toString()));
            // The above line of code causes the stackOverflow
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing an infinite loop because you are setting the text again in your text changed listener. The easiest fix for this is using a boolean flag to filter out the events which are not caused by the user. Try something like this:

```
private boolean userChange = true;

private void writeNewMsg() {
    final EditText newMsgText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.s4_et_message);
    newMsgText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (userChange) {
                // Event is invoked by the user, set flag to false to ignore the event caused by the following setText()
                userChange = false;

                // Save current selection so you can reapply it after setText()
                int selection = newMsgText.getSelectionStart();

                newMsgText.setText(Smiley.getSmiledText(Messaging.this, newMsgText.getText().toString()));

                // Reapply the previous selection
                newMsgText.setSelection(selection);
            } else {
                // Ignore this event, reset flag so next user interaction will not be ignored.
                userChange = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }
    });
}
```

Of course this is just a quick workaround. You will probably need a more elaborate solution in your app. Nevertheless this example should be enough to illustrate the basics to you.

Comment: You would need to save the current selection before you call `setText()` and reapply it afterwards. But you should listen to what @CommonsWare said. Setting the whole text each time is not that smart.

Comment: I edited my answer. Didn't test it but it should work.